# React typeError, useState doesnt work. but I dont know why

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

[image: This err is occurred when I run my program.]

[image: I try to check through console.log(res.data). it is work. I used useState, but User value is null. I don't know why]

TypeError is occurred. when I run my code.
You can see I tried to check (res.data) that is work.
but I use useState , and setUser(res.data) but User value is null.
I don't know why.

Comment: Please, copy code, not images. Images are a really bad way to show code or errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` *starts* as `null`. That's the value it will have until `setUser`.
The error occurs on `User.profilePicture ? User.profilePicture : ...`, because you are trying to access a propriety from `User`, which is `null`.

To solve it, first check if the value exist, and then check if the propriety exist.

```
User && User.profilePicture ? User.profilePicture : ...
```

Comment: thank you for metion! I solved this error.